# PHP testing user input for certin value range

Tags: php

I cant seem to figure out how to make a php if stament to tell if the user inputed a numeric value and in the certin range value.

```
 <form name="heat.php" class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get The Heat Index</legend>
        Tempeture <input type="text" name="temp"><br>
        Humidity <input type="text" name="hum"><br>
      <input id="submit"type="submit" value="Get The Heat Index">
     </feildset>   
 </form>
 <?php 
 $temp=
 $hum="";  
 if (empty($temp) && empty($hum) && ("80" <= $temp) && ($temp >= "112") && ("13" <= $hum) && ($hum >= "85")) //validates temp input 
  {
    echo "The temperature should be a number between 80 and 112. 
        The humidity should be a number between 13 and 85. Please try again.";
  } else{

  }
?>
```

Once user inputs the correct data the else will happen but if its not a correct number or outside of the range value then they will get the error message.

Comment: try is_numeric, https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/is_numeric.php
and for the range ($min <= $value) && ($value <= $max)

Comment: In order for that code to run, ALL the conditions have to be true because you're using `&&` checks. How can it be empty *and* greater than 112?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar if you want to provide a link, best do it to the manual. https://php.net/is_numeric

Comment: @miken32 ok noted!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one check - just use [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Example:

```
filter_var(
    $value, 
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    [
        'options' => [
            'max_range' => 10, 
            'min_range' => 4
        ]
    ]
)
```

This will return the value as `integer` for all values passed in that are an integer and between 4 and 10. (both inclusive!). If the passed value does not fit the parameters, it will return false. If you do *not* want that `false` is returned you can specify a default return value:

```
filter_var(
    $value, 
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    [
        'options' => [
            'max_range' => 10, 
            'min_range' => 4,
            'default' => 5
        ]
    ]
)
```

And the working code: https://3v4l.org/JZ54r

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that works as follows:

```
<?php
const minHum = 13;
const maxHum = 85;
const minTemp = 80;
const maxTemp = 112;

$temp = 0;
$hum  = 0;
$message = "";

$arrOptions = [["options" => ["min_range"=>minTemp, "max_range"=>maxTemp]],
   ["options" => ["min_range"=>minHum, "max_range"=>maxHum]]];

$arrShouldBe = ["The temperature should be a number between 80 and 112.",
   "The humidity should be a number between 13 and 85. Please try again."];


function failed2Validate($var,$arr){
      if ( filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $arr)== false)  {
             return true;
      }
      return false;
}

function validate($temp,$hum,$arrOptions, $arrShouldBe){
     $i=0;
     $message = "";
     $arrFuncs = [failed2Validate($temp,$arrOptions[0]), failed2Validate($hum,$arrOptions[1])];
     $count = count($arrFuncs);
     while ($i < $count) {
          $message = $arrFuncs[$i]? $arrShouldBe[$i]: "Success";
          if ($message != "Success"){
               break;
          }
          $i++;
     }
     return $message;
}

/******* START ******/
if ( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) { 
   if ( !isset($_POST['temp']) || !isset($_POST['hum']) ) { 
      $message = "No data, No dice";
   }
   // check that data is numeric 
   else 
   if( ctype_digit($_POST['temp']) && ctype_digit($_POST['hum']) ) {
          [$temp,$hum] = [ $_POST['temp'], $_POST['hum']]; 
   }
   else
   { //coerce data into numeric values
        [$temp,$hum] = [(int) $_POST['temp'], (int) $_POST['hum']]; 
   }  

   if ($message != "No data, No dice") {
     $message = validate($temp,$hum,$arrOptions, $arrShouldBe);
   }
   echo $message;
?>



<html>
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get The Heat Index</legend>
        Tempeture <input type="text" name="temp"><br>
        Humidity <input type="text" name="hum"><br>
      <input name="submit" id="submit"type="submit" value="Get The Heat Index">
     </feildset>   
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

See simulated POST with slightly modified PHP code [here](https://3v4l.org/qYVFj).

The name attribute of the OP's form seems oddly reminiscent if a PHP filename. So, I changed it to `myform`. More info about the name attribute in HTML form  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

One line of code, namely `$temp=` will produce a parser error.  Interestingly, you may write a statement, like `$temp;`.

One needs to be careful with logic when using empty() vs isset() since with respect to a variable that has not been assigned a value or is set to null, empty() returns true unlike isset() which returns false.

Most importantly, user-submitted data should be treated as tainted.  So, in this case, the code checks to see if the user submitted values.  If so, then the data is tested to see whether it is numeric.  If not, then the code casts the POST data to integers. In the OP's code sample there is no code indicating that POSTed data was assigned to any variables.  In fact, the OP's code never tests that a form was even submitted, therefore I inserted code to test for that circumstance.

Lastly, the comparisons need the correct order, i.e. if a user enters 90 for the temperature then the test ("80" <= $temp) will always return true, but if you reverse the operands, i.e. ($temp <= "80") then you can detect accurately whether user submitted a temperature in the desired range or if an error has occurred.

Note: I originally revised my answer having been inspired by the example that kuh-chan provides using filter_var().